# Can \pgfpoint be used to define a \coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, coordinates

Can a `\pgfpoint` be used to define a `\coordinate` as in the following example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0, 0) -- \pgfpoint{2}{2};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have a `\newcommand` that calculates `\pgfpoint`'s and I would like to avoid a duplication of code.

Comment: No, but you can use `\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2}{2}}\pgfusepath{draw}` (and a few other commands to set the line width, color, arrow style, etc.).

Comment: @JohnKormylo How should I tell that I need to draw a blue arrow?

Comment: It is all described in section IX Basic Layer of the TikZ manual. Start and end with `\pgfscope` and `\endpgfscope`.  `\pgfsetstrokecolor{bllue}` and `\pgfsetarrowsend{Computer Modern Rightarrow}` should do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to name the coordinate before you can use it in a path.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfcoordinate{A}{\pgfpoint{2}{2}}
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As indicated in the comments, you can also use the basic layer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{2}{2}}
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{blue}
  \pgfsetarrowsend{>}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there perhaps also the opposite of `\pgfcoordinate{A}{\pgfpoint{2}{2}}` - converting a `\coordinate` to `\pgfpoint`?

Comment: Can the `\pgfcoordinate` be passed anonymously as in   `\draw[->] (0,0) -- (\pgfcoordinate{}{\pgfpoint{2}{2}})`;

Comment: @Viesturs “You *have to name the coordinate* before you can use it in a path.”  Wasn't that clear enough?