# Can a \coordinate be used to define a \pgfpoint?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

In this example due to @henri-menke ([Can \pgfpoint be used to define a \coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399683/can-pgfpoint-be-used-to-define-a-coordinate/399711#399711)) a `\pgfpoint` is used to define a `\coordinate`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfcoordinate{A}{\pgfpoint{2}{2}}
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can one do the opposite as in the following example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2, 2);
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{??? \pgfcoordinate{A}}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly...

`\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}`

See "Using Anchors" p.1030 in the manual for `3.0.1a`

Comment: @Viesturs Does the answer solved your problem? If yes you could [accept](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer). Otherwise let us know what do you think about it or what is missing.